How can I enable Chrome browser extensions for specific domains/URLs (and disable them for others)?
I have and use a lot of Chrome browser extensions in my browser (Brave on macOS). A few of these are only useful for certain sites/domains/URLs I visit (e.g. PocketTube for YouTube) and some are used less with less regularity than others.
My problem
In my browser's Task Manager, I've noticed these extensions appear to be passively consuming resources and some are further creating subframes for each open tab (I tend to have a lot open at a time). I think these might be contributing to my laptop running hot when my browser is open (almost always), so I want to minimise that. It doesn't seem efficient to have certain extensions always enabled and consuming resources when they're only used on specific domains/URLs.
Current solution
I currently manage my extensions using SimpleExtManager. It's useful but not particularly convenient for quickly enabling/disabling extensions.
My question
Is there a way I can trigger the enabling and disabling of Chrome extensions by domain/URL? E.g. a whitelist for extensions where they automatically enable when a tab opens a specific domain/URL and disable when a tab with a matching domain/URL isn't open?

You can use Extension Manager:

Go to its settings -> Rules
Add a new rule with chosen extensions or predefined group of extensions.
Add a condition to match by URL, even regexes are supported.
Set it to Enable Only When Matched


Amazing!  That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for - thank you.
